# Unbiased Sample variance concern

Tags: statistics

I have a concern with the unbiased sample variance that I can't seem to understand.
$$S^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=0}^{N}(x_i-\bar{x})^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x^2}_i}{N-1}-\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\right)^2}{N(N-1)}$$ Now I can't understand the right hand side, surely from the fact that $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$  shouldn't the $N$ in the denominator be squared as well as $$E(X)=\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\right)}{N}$$ And also there is no $N$ in the denominator for the first term, why is that? Isn't $$E(X^2)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x^2}_i}{N}$$ I know the top formula is correct as I have calculated examples, I'm just failing to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole slew of questions in this posting.

Get clear about one thing before attempting to think about the rest of this: the "unbiased sample variance" is *not* supposed to be the variance of a probability distribution; rather it is supposed to be an *estimate*, based on a sample taken from a large population, of the variance of the population.  Some things that apply to variances of probability distributions simply do not apply to the "unbiased sample variance"; for example: the variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of their separate variances.  That *does not* apply to this!

The quantity $\bar x =(x_1+\cdots+x_N)/N$ is the *sample* average, not the *population* average.  Suppose $\mu$ is the population average.  Then the expected value of
$$
\frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu)^2 \tag 1
$$
would be $\sigma^2$.  Putting $\bar x$ in place of $\mu$ moves that subtracted quantity closer to the observed values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, thereby replacing the sum $(1)$ with a smaller number.  Then changing $N$ to $N-1$ makes it larger again, so that it is again something whose average value is $\sigma^2$.  That last step is "Bessel's correction", named after Friedrich Bessel, who is better known as the eponym of Bessel functions.

Now let's do some algebra:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\bar x)^2 & = \sum _{i=1}^N (x_i^2 - 2\bar x x_i + \bar x^2) \\[12pt]
& = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i^2)\right) - 2\bar x\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^N (\bar x^2). \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
The reason that $2\bar x$ can be pulled out of the sum is simply that it does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $N$.  The same happens with the very last sum above:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N  (\bar x^2) = \bar x^2\sum_{i=1}^N 1 = N\bar x^2.
$$
The second sum in $(2)$ is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = N\bar x.
$$
Hence $(1)$ becomes
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i^2)\right) - 2N\bar x^2 + N\bar x^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i^2)\right) - N\bar x^2. \tag 3
$$
Now one can divide both sides by $N-1$.

But the last term in $(3)$ can be written thus:
$$
N \bar x^2 = N\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}\right)^2 = \frac 1 N\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^2.
$$

Comment: A very concise and informative answer, thanks!